linear algebra basics - why full rank square matrix A guarantees $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ as identity matrix but full rank rectangular matrix A not
Given on $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, easily we can verify $A=PA$
so the questions are

how to interprete P matrix
if A is square full rank matrix, P is guaranteed to be identity matrix. why is that? can it be proved?
if A is non-square full rank matrix, P is not necessarily to be identity. why is that? can it be proved?


For every matrix $A$, the expression $A(A^T A)^{-1} A^T$ gives the orthogonal projector onto the image of $A$. If $A$ is full rank, this is the identity

@VladimirLysikov maybe I'm asking some basics - if A is square full rank, this is identity. But if A is not square, then it's not...why is that?
tmp = np.random.rand(5,2)
tmp @ np.linalg.inv(tmp.T @ tmp) @ tmp.T

you should edit your question into mathematical language. Not everyone can read numpy code. I'm voting to close until you make the language mathematically explicit then i'll be happy to re-open

@SidharthGhoshal sorry about that - i'm editing now

@SidharthGhoshal i just edited. can you please reopen it?

I think I can guess what your question is but your question body still doesn't make sense. I think the question you want to ask is "I understand why if $P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ that $A = PA$ but I do not understand why this property does not hold when $A$ is a rectangular matrix." then you should explain HOW you understand the first fact (if you understand it at all), then lastly you should mention: "I found this problem when experimenting with numpy code, here is the code attached for those curious". This may be difficult if english is a second language in which case just take your time.

also this tool http://approach0.xyz can be used to find old questions that are similar. Are any of these links helpful?

@SidharthGhoshal thanks for comments. I actually don't understand both scnearios that 1)  A is square full rank matrix, it guarantees to be identity 2) A is non-square full rank matrix, it is not necessarily to be identity
so i want to know is it possible to prove it.

awesome edits, the question is a lot clearer now. Generally stackexchange frowns on asking multiple questions at once, but ill give you a pass this one time and vote to re-open + upvote. With that in mind I think this addresses bulletpoint (3). let me know if that is helpful

you would still benefit greatly from mentioning what your attempts to prove have been as well as, how you found this question (namely experimentally by code). That added context helps other askers really see where you are coming from and how best to communicate with you.

@SidharthGhoshal much appreciated for the help. This is my first time to ask questions in stackexchange so hopefully it will be improved next time. and I do find couple of interesting answers from the search webiste - really helpful and can search formula easily - thanks for that

Let us answer all three questions you asked (albeit not in the order you propose for didactic purposes).


if $A$ is square full rank matrix, $P$ is guaranteed to be identity matrix. why is that? can it be proved?


Indeed, if $A$ is a square full rank matrix, then $A$ is invertible, so $A^T$ is. Hence, $\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}=A^{-1}\left(A^T\right)^{-1}$, and
$$P=A\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T=AA^{-1}\left(A^T\right)^{-1}A^T=I.$$


if $A$ is non-square full rank matrix, $P$ is not necessarily to be identity. why is that? can it be proved?


Suppose now that $A$ is an $n\times m$ non-square full matrix. First of all, we need to clarify that $\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}$ only make sense if $A$ has linearly independent columns, i.e., $A$ is full rank and has more rows than columns ($m\leq n$). Under this assumption, $A$ has a left inverse, that means, there exists some $m\times n$ matrix $B$ such that $BA=I_m$.
Now, let us suppose that $P=I$. Then $P=A\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T=I_n$. Denoting by $C:=\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T$, we obtain that $AC=I_n$, i.e., $A$ has also a right inverse. This only occurs when $A$ has linearly independent rows, i.e., $A$ has full rank and $n\leq m$. Hence $A$ satisifies both that $n\leq m$ and $m\leq n$, namely, $n=m$ and concluding that $A$ is square, contradicting our main assumption that $A$ is non-square.
To sum up, $P$ is not necessarily the identity. What is more, it is only the identity if and only if $A$ is square (connecting to Question 2).


how to interprete $P$ matrix


As you first noticed in the first line of your post: $PA=A$. One way to think of this equality is the following: if $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is some column of $A$, then $P\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{a}$. That is to say, $P$ is a map that fixes the columns of $A$. Not only that, but if $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is any vector, then $A\mathbf{x}=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\mathbf{a}_i$, where $\mathbf{a}_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$ an by the associativity of the product, $P(A\mathbf{x})=(PA)\mathbf{x}=A\mathbf{x}$. In other words, $P$ fixes any linear combination of the columns of $A$. In other words: $\operatorname{Fix}P=\operatorname{ran}(A)$, where $\operatorname{ran}(A)$ is the range or image of $A$. Not only that, but for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $P\mathbf{x}=A\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T\mathbf{x}=A\mathbf{x}'\in\operatorname{ran}(A)$, where $\mathbf{x}':=\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T\mathbf{x}$. Hence, we have proven that $\operatorname{ran}P\subseteq\operatorname{ran}A$, and since $\operatorname{Fix}P=\operatorname{ran}(A)$, then $PP=P$. This proves that $P$ is, in fact, a projection onto $\operatorname{ran}A$.
Nevertheless, this is not only any kind of projection, but particularly the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{ran}(A)$. To see this, we need to verify that the vector with direction from $\mathbf{x}$ to $P\mathbf{x}$ is orthogonal to any vector lying on $\operatorname{ran}(A)$, i.e., a vector from $P\mathbf{x}$ to some other $A\mathbf{x}'$. Hence, we need to prove that $(\mathbf{x}-P\mathbf{x})^T(P\mathbf{x}-A\mathbf{y})=0$. By doing some computations, we end up with the following:
$$(\mathbf{x}-P\mathbf{x})^T(P\mathbf{x}-A\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{x}^T(I-P)(P\mathbf{x}-A\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{x}^T(P\mathbf{x}-PP\mathbf{x}-A\mathbf{y}+PA\mathbf{y})$$
However, if we recall the previous computations, $P=PP$, so $P\mathbf{x}-PP\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ and by your first statement, $PA=A$, so $-A\mathbf{y}+PA\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{0}$, obtaining the desired orthogonality.
To sum up, $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{ran}(A)$,  as Vladimir Lysikov noted firstly in the comments. If $A$ is square and full rank, then $A$ would be invertible and $\operatorname{ran}(A)$ would be the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$, so projecting onto the whole space is, essentially, doing nothing, justifying why $P=I$ (connecting to Question 2). If $A$ is not square, then $\operatorname{ran}(A)$ is not the whole space and $P$ is actually projecting, explaining why $P\neq I$ (connecting to Question 1).
Appendix: The Moore-Penrose generalized inverse
This particular question is, in fact, a particular case of the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse. This is a way to extend the notion of the matrix inverse to the case of non-square matrices. In particular, for all $A$ real $n\times m$ matrix, there exists a unique $m\times n$ matrix $A^+$ such that $AA^+A=A$ and $A^+AA^+=A^+$ (this would hold for complex matrices as well with some slight adjustments). On the other hand, it is well kown that $AA^+$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{ran}A$ (as we deduced before).
If $A$ has linearly independent columns, then it can be shown that $A^+=\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A$. Hence, your inquired matrix was in fact $P=AA^+$, so by the previous paragraph the fact that $P=AA^+$ was the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{ran}A$ follows straightforwardly. Finally, under this assumption, $P$ is not the identity in general, but $A^+A=I$ always holds.
